# Is there a reason to use warnings before use strict?

Tags: perl, pragma

I remember seeing some comment somewhere that

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

was preferable (rather than use'ing `strict` first, as I was wont to do). Is my memory correct? Does the order matter and, if it does, in what way?

Comment: Once I saw this guy on a bridge about to jump. I said, "Don't do it!" He said, "I don't want to live anymore." I said, "What do you do for a living?" He said, "I develop software." I said, "Me, too! Desktop or Web?" He said, "Web." I said, "Me, too! Front-end or back-end?" He said, "Back-end." I said, "Me, too! Perl or Java?" He said, "Perl." I said, "Me, too! Old-school or following the Modern movement?" He said, "Modern Perl." I said, "Me, too! Warnings before strictures in the boilerplate or vice-versa?" He said, "Warnings first." I said, "Die, heretic!" And I pushed him over.

Comment: filked from http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Emo_Philips

Comment: Perl::Critic complains, or at least used to, if you don't put warnings first. That might be where you picked up the impression.

Comment: I figure that not using `use strict;` should be a warning, to I put `use strict;` first :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't see how there is any technical reason for the order being significant. I always put `use strict` first as it happens but for no reason other than I've always done that!

Comment: I can't either but somehow there is this nagging memory of a comment by someone I must have trusted, so I want to lay this to rest once and for all ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Simple: If you do `use strict` before you do `use warnings`, you won't get a warning if you're using `use strict` wrong. DUH!

Actually, I've always done it the other way. The anal retentive in me made me put the two pragmas alphabetically. I never knew there was a reason to do it one way or another.

Heck, [perldoc use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) shows placing `use strict` before `use warnings`, and that's what I've seen in most of the official Perl examples.

I suspect there's a cultural reason. Originally in Perl, to use warnings, you use to use

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -W
```

on the first line of your program. The `use strict` pragma came later, and only later was `use warnings` a pragma. Thus, programs (for a while) were written as:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -W

use strict;
```

When the `-W` parameter fell out of fashion, you simply added `use warnings` right below the shebang:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
```

One of the things I like about Stackoverflow is that you can learn new things you never knew before. I'd love to see if someone has an actual reason why it should be one way and not another.

Answer (score 3):

I thought, maybe, on Perl 5.8.9 and older where `strict` does not warn when you `use Strict` on case insensitive file systems, having `warnings` first would help. I built 5.8.9 on my Windows XP system and it does not:

```
C:\Temp> cat t.pl
use warnings;
use Strict;

C:\Temp> c:\opt\perl-5.8.9\bin\perl.exe t.pl

C:\Temp>
```

That was a shot in the dark. I am led to conclude that so long as there are no intervening statements, the order is immaterial.